# How to terminate a workflow due to error/exception

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have a workflow that converts a docx to pdf then does some more processing on the document.

I would like to kill/terminate/cancel the workflow if the conversion fails but I am not sure the best way to do this.  Do I just throw an exception and let that kill the workflow?  I would like to leave a useful message in the history other than "Error Occurred" that could help with debugging.

I have a couple other areas in the code where I would also like to be able to kill the workflow and leave a useful History message and outcome.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I actually try to handle the exception first and write some meaningful event log otherwise I let it bubble. Check out these links and decide a method most suitable for you -

[MSDN Description of Workflow Fault Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734771.aspx)

[Fault Handling in SharePoint Workflow](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/fault-handling-in-sharepoint-workflows/)

[Example of error handling and writing event logs in SharePoint Workflow](http://glorix.blogspot.in/2007/03/spd-workflow-activity-creating-document.html)